# How to take a preview img from a Video in FileList? HTML React

Tags: html, reactjs, image, video

I'm handling this situation where I have

```
 {currentFile.type.includes('video') ? (
      <video
        width='auto'
        height='400'
        src={URL.createObjectURL(currentFile)}
        controls={'controls'}
      >
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    ) : (
      <img
        src={URL.createObjectURL(currentFile)}
      />
    )}
```

So that's working because if I upload a video I can watch it as same as an image but I want to show a video preview in form of an image. something like whatsapp does!

[image]

Look when you drop a video on Whatsapp Web you can see it and down you can see an image like a preview!, do you have any idea how to reach that behavior ? Thanks!

Comment: Using just Javascript and HTML5 API's... **(1)** You could have a function to start play and also immediately pause the video. That way you get a paused frame 1 as preview. **(2)** You can use `<canvas>` to  draw a frame of the video and then use that as your image data.

Comment: Thanks buddy ! Fortunely I already solve this problem with this little library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/capture-video-frame

I'm handling other challenges related now. Thanks for your answer @VC.One